# How to resize images with maintaining quality

Tags: c#, image, crop, image-resizing, image-quality

I am trying to resize image to 500x500 px. Using below code:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

But this just resizes horizontally and not doing cropping! Someone suggested me to crop the image to a centered 1:1 ratio and then downscale it.
I also wish to increase size of image to 500x500 if it is less than it.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: if you are using WPF than probably that could be easily be done using `ImageBrush` with playing the properties like `ViewboxUnits="Absolute" Viewbox, Viewport`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava i am not using WPF but asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
```

Use

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0,0,500,500);
graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

and you can also read more about `DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped`  for cropping purpose.

Comment: what do i pass to cropRect ?

Comment: It would be cropped rectangle on the image. So if the image is the bigger in size you can pass the 500*500 rectangle.

Comment: when i paste your code then i get error cannot resolve symbol cropRect

Comment: Also cant we crop it as square instead rectangle

Comment: you can read about the arguments in of [DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx) I'll update my code as well

Comment: if i want 640 *640 then how i create rectangle using this code 
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 150, 150);

Comment: `Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(50, 50, 690, 690);`

Comment: Can we also make square? Also what was issue with my earlier code ?

Comment: Can we make square like new rectangle(0,0,640,640)

Comment: Yes you can make square from rectangle function. Rentangle function takes four int type parameters. which can make either a rectangle or Square on the basis of the parameters passed to this Object. **2** Draw image have [30 overloaded function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.110).aspx) you yourself can have a look on it.

Comment: So what was issue with my approach?

Comment: I am not sure about that ... Once I have faced the same problem with image cropping and this idea worked which I shared with you. So I thought this might help you. :)

Comment: i tried but it cuts the content of image so its of no use. Am i right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88718/discussion-between-happy-and-mohit-shrivastava).